# How to use Dubins to complete a continuous-curvature path for Ackermann vehicle with Boustrophedon line segments as input?

Tags: path-planning

Has anyone out there, who has worked with Ackermann steering vehicles, crafted a continuous-curvature path planning approach that uses the Python library Dubins shortest path to connect end points of already prepared line segments to create a complete coverage map?  I created my line segments using a Boustrophedon coverage map approach at 0.9 meter line separation and a polygon of my yard. My robot (a lawn tractor) has a turning radius of 1.5 meters. I have to handle sometimes the end point of the 'from' line segment is shorter than the starting point of the next 'to' line segment; Sometimes its the reverse.  I also have to handle that the robot can't go up to the intersection of the line segment and the edge of the polygon since it needs to stop sooner and allow for the turning radius of the Ackermann vehicle.  I'm crafting my own approach, but thought I would ask in case someone wants to share or collaborate.  I've looked at scholarly articles on continuous curvature and amazing python work by Atsushi Sakai that is helpful, but not plug and play.

My background repo: https://github.com/jones2126/ros1_lawn_tractor_ws